# How to apply 'IN' constraint to the fields of django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, constraints

I want that one of the fields of the model can take only some specific values say a and b. This can be achieved normally in sql by adding the 'IN' constraint. How can I achieve the same using django model class fields.

eg.

`Some field say fruits can have values 'banana' and 'orange' only`

Please help. I am new to django.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're referring to [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#choices).

Example from the docs:

```
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
        (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
        (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
        (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
    )
    year_in_school = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                      choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
                                      default=FRESHMAN)
```

Comment: @mevius : thanks for your response ! will this method is_upperclass check while inserting the value into database table student that it can have  these two values only ?

Comment: No, the `choice` argument will limit possible values to the 4 listed.

Comment: i mean year_in_school can have these 2 values junior and senior?

Comment: It can have a total of 4 choices. Everything listed in the tuple is a choice: `'FR'`, `'SO'`, `'JR'`, and `'SR'`. If you only want two choices, limit the tuple to two items

Comment: @mevious: I think you did not understand the question. I know that it will limit it to 4 choices but if a user tries to do an Insert in this way .. `insert into Student values ('infant')`, so will it throw an error to the user, wrong value or something ? because I did this only and inserted some other value than these 4 values but it did not throw any error .

Comment: just a warning and decreased the length to 2 for inserting infant and made it 'in' instead of infant in the table

Comment: However, choices don't constraint the data: https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/01/22/djangos-field-choices-dont-constrain-your-data/

Answer (score 0):

As [Raunaqss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1468573/raunaqss) pointed out, the accepted solution does not actually constraint the data at the database level, so you might end up with irregularities in your database if you don't actually enforce it.

If this is an issue for you, here is a way to actually apply said constraints, using the accepted answer's example:

```
from django.db import models

class YearInSchoolChoices(models.TextChoices):
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'

class Student(models.Model):
    year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=2, choices=YearInSchoolChoices.choices
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                name="%(class)s_year_in_school_valid",
                check=models.Q(year_in_school__in=YearInSchoolChoices.values),
            )
        ]
```

Remember to then run `makemigrations`, possibly manually adding some data migration code to the beginning of the generated migration in order to clean up eventual invalid rows:

```
def clean_up_invalid_years(apps, schema_editor):
    Student = apps.get_model("students", "Student")

    for row in Student.objects.all().reverse():
        if row.year_in_school not in YearInSchoolChoices.values:
            row.delete()
```

(You may have to copy the `YearInSchoolChoices` class into the migration since it cannot be imported)